Finding HASH algorithm and coding/decoding that in link address
I am using a website which is an online map service. every tile in this map service has a unique address and it is consist of X,Y,Z and R value. R value is only dependent on X and Y values (I think). In a constant Z (zoom level), for all tiles in a diagonal order, R values are constant. I need to help me find the algorithm which is used to encrypt the XYZ values and convert them to R value. R value has 32 characters and it is possible that it could be separated as 8digit-4digit-4digit-4digit-12digit grouping.
Below you can see some tiles links:
https://map.mimt.gov.ir/SafaTGLive/maptile.ashx?x=21911&y=13576&z=15&Key=M10&r=01222be88e737a1ec4c95eb10d7d4876
https://map.mimt.gov.ir/SafaTGLive/maptile.ashx?x=21912&y=13576&z=15&Key=M10&r=8cfdb1b6210d2809f6742ace77668355
https://map.mimt.gov.ir/SafaTGLive/maptile.ashx?x=336&y=215&z=9&Key=M10&r=0850c213e9bab24b7ebc7387d44a381e
https://map.mimt.gov.ir/SafaTGLive/maptile.ashx?x=22107&y=13838&z=15&Key=m10&r=dcf4d5580cea3fc1b57e4625171602bd

I need to help me find the algorithm which is used to encrypt the XYZ values and convert them to R value.
